# facebook app invite notification won't go away even though delete comes back ok

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, urllib

I have a facebook app and have it working far enough that users can invite friends, but I can't seem to delete the notifications.

I'm in python, on Django, using urllib to issue the delete request thusly:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('graph.facebook.com')
user = request.facebook.user
t = urllib.quote(user.oauth_token.token)
conn.request("DELETE", '/%s_%s?access_token=%s' %(request_id, uid, t))
print(conn.getresponse().reason)
```

So I'm getting "OK" back as the .reason, but the notifications aren't going away.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: is your app marked as "Requests 2.0 Efficient"? (I do not know whether this would help though)

Comment: It wasn't, I marked it as such, but it doesn't seem to help....

Answer (score 0):

You should notice that the request_id returned by FB **sometimes has many IDs**. For example, if 2 or more friends invite you to use an application, Facebook may join those request_id to one string. The request_id params may have the format `"A_FacebookId,B_FacebookId`".

You must split the parameters to retrieves the correct id, and **delete them one by one**. So far it works well for me.